# Displaying urls with embedded content (djs v12)

Tags: discord.js, embed

I am looking to display a image / gif url in the embed, if it has embedded content it will show it along with the url. Currently, I only figured out how to display if the message was uploaded to discord as a attachment.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTYLd.jpg), the avatar is shown within the embed. This is the same concept I want for images with embedded content.

```
 const embed = new MessageEmbed()
 
   

      .setDescription(message.content)
      .setColor("#E74C3C")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setImage(message.attachments.array().length == 0 ? null:message.attachments.first().url)
      .setAuthor(
        message.author.tag,
        message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })
      
    );
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your problem? are you trying to make it so it shows the URL along with the embedded content of it **within the embed**??

Comment: yea thats basically it

Comment: You are unable to do that the content of the embedded URL is already an embed you can't nest embeds like that it either has to be a message or just the content of the URL

Comment: So you're unable to display the content of the URL, that is what I am looking to do. Sorry if what I'm saying does not make any sense at all, I haven't slept in a while.

Comment: I'm sorry could you like attach an example to your question of what you're attempting to do? I'm honestly confused as in what you're trying to achieve lol

Comment: For example, take a look at [this](https://imgur.com/hT3OkkX). The users avatar is shown in the embed, I am trying to make it a for a image or gif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand is you are trying to set an image into your embed of an already existing image to the embed that shows while we put our URL.

You can simply use the [`MessageEmbed`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) constructor's [`MessageEmbed#setImage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setImage) method along with extracting the image from the link as the URL parameter to the method like so ( for that you need to send it to discord first ) :

```js
    const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
    message.channel.send("https://discord.com/").then( (embeddedmessage) => {
    let image = embeddedmessage.embeds[0].thumbnail.url
    const x = new MessageEmbed()
    x.setTitle("Discord URL's Image")
    x.setImage(image);
    embeddedmessage.edit(x);
    });
```

The message with the URL ( if has an embed ) would have an rich embed object which would justify the image present within it ( here is the example object from the [URL](https://discord.com/) we took in our code:

```json
{
    "title": "Discord | Your Place to Talk and Hang Out",
    "type": "rich",
    "description": "Discord is the easiest way to talk over voice, video, and text. Talk, chat, hang out, and stay close with your friends and communities.",
    "url": "https://discord.com/",
    "timestamp": null,
    "color": null,
    "fields": [],
    "thumbnail": {
        "url": "https://discord.com/assets/652f40427e1f5186ad54836074898279.png",
        "proxyURL": "https://images-ext-2.discordapp.net/external/pL0w57uLXr8vYKityoLlH1CVuGCs0fB5xnrWKO8Fqoo/https/discord.com/assets/652f40427e1f5186ad54836074898279.png",
        "height": 630,
        "width": 1200
    },
    "image": null,
    "author": null,
    "footer": null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try .setURL() ?

```
if(message.attachments.size > 0) {
  embed.setURL(message.attachments.first().url)
}
```

Comment: Discord embeds can very well have GIFs although the OP is asking something else , let them clarify.

Comment: @ignshifts it will make the title become a link

Comment: @Zero oh I forgot it , sorry for the wrong information